# Combining arrays without product method

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-1.8

I have two arrays

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  
b = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

that I need to combine to create:

```
c = [[1,a],[1,b],[1,c],[1,d],[1,e],[1,f],[2,a],[2,b],...]
```

I would use the `product` method with Ruby version 1.9 or later, but I am running an old version of Ruby, and this method does not exist. I am not sure how to create `c` without the use of the `product` method. Can any suggestions be offered?

Comment: It's a primitive double-loop, isn't it?

Comment: Please don’t confuse Ruby with Ruby on Rails, they are two completely different things, and their names have more in common than they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to get the Cartesian product.

I've created a class called `CartesianArray` that inherits from `Array` and gives you a `#product` method.

```
class CartesianArray < Array

  def initialize(array_one, array_two)
    @array_one, @array_two = array_one, array_two
  end

  def product
    results = []
    @array_one.each do |a1|
      @array_two.each do { |a2| results << [a1, a2] }
    end

    results
  end

end
```

You could use it like this:

```
# Test Code
numbers = [1,2,3,4]
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

cart_array = CartesianArray.new(numbers, letters)
p cart_array.product
[[1, "a"], [1, "b"], [1, "c"], [1, "d"], [1, "e"], [1, "f"], [2, "a"], [2, "b"], [2, "c"], [2, "d"], [2, "e"], [2, "f"], [3, "a"], [3, "b"], [3, "c"], [3, "d"], [3, "e"], [3, "f"], [4, "a"], [4, "b"], [4, "c"], [4, "d"], [4, "e"], [4, "f"]]
```

If you don't like keeping it in that class, then i'm pretty sure you could just pull out the `#product` method and modify it to fit your code.

Comment: The core part is good, but I don't think it makes sense to put that in a subclass of Array. You are not using either of the array as the receiver, nor are you using it as a class method.

Comment: @sawa I see what you're saying.  I think that steenslag 's approach is pretty great then. Monkey patching Array with product is closer to what ryan1393402 would be used to from 1.9.  Additionally, I think the end solution should take an arbitrary number of arrays instead of just two.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.map {|ma| b.map { |mb| [ma, mb]} }
```

Comment: This results in too much nesting (compared with the `product` method).

Comment: This comment is correct, I would ideally like to see the most efficient method for replicating the `product` method exactly.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Array
  def product(other)
    if block_given? then
      each {|el| other.each {|other_el| yield [el, other_el]}}
    else
      res=[]
      each{|el| other.each {|other_el| res << [el, other_el]}}
      res
    end
  end
end

a = [1,2,3,4]  
b = %w(a b c d e f)

p a.product(b) #[[1, "a"], [1, "b"], [1, "c"],...
a.product(b){|e| puts e.join}
#1a
#1b
#1c
#1d...
```

For a recent Ruby version there would be a `return to_enum unless block_given?`somewhere in this code, but AFAIK `to_enum`is not available in old Rubies. The real `product` takes multiple arguments; I have not found a way to do that nonrecursive yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = a.map{|x| b.map{|y| [x,y]}}.flatten(1)
```

Depending on how old your Ruby version is, you may need to use:

```
c = a.map{|x| b.map{|y| [x,y]}}.inject([],:concat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are easier and more efficient ways to do it than -

```
(a+b).combination(2).map {|c| c if a.include?(c.join.to_i)}.compact
```

but I enjoy different possible one liners you can write in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

## Backports gem

The easiest way to get `Array#product` in older Rubies would be to use the [backports gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/backports). It adds this method [to Ruby 1.87](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/1.8.7/array/product.rb) and [Ruby 1.9.2](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/1.9.2/array/product.rb).